# PHP - Not recognizing an object

Tags: php

I have a method that is built to delete multiple users from a database based on their username. The username can be pulled as just a username or an email if that is provided instead. I'm using routes built from composer. When testing the route from Postman, it worked just fine, but when calling the route from my webpage, I'm getting the error

> {"invalid_email":[],"invalid_username":[""]}
>   **Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **/Path/model/users.php** on line **205**

I'm not sure why because I am pulling from my User object, which worked in previous testing.

This is the route call:

```
$app->delete("/multiple_users", function($request, $response, $args){
  $body = $request->getParsedBody();
  $sessionKey = $request->getQueryParams()['session_key'];
  $sessionID = $request->getQueryParams()['session_id'];
  $users = $body['users'];
  global $database;
  $statement = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM session WHERE session_key =  AND id = ?");
  $statement->execute(array($sessionKey, $sessionID));
  if($statement->rowCount()==0){
      return send_error($response, "invalid admin session", 403);
  }
  $deletion_progress = User::delete_multiple_students($users);
  return $response->withJSON($deletion_progress);
});
```

This is the method erroring:

```
public static function delete_multiple_students($users){
    $invalid_users = array("invalid_email" => array(), "invalid_username" => array());
    $usernames = explode(",", $users);

    foreach($usernames as $username){
        if (strpos($username, '@') !== false) {
            if(!preg_match("/@email.address$/", $username)){
                array_push($invalid_users["invalid_email"], $username);
            }else{
                $name = preg_replace("/@.+/", "", $username);
                $user_id = self::get_by_username($name)->user_id; // error is right here when first in the list is a email
                if (!$user_id){
                    array_push($invalid_users["invalid_email"], $username);
                }
                self::delete_student($user_id);
            }
        }else{
            $user_id = self::get_by_username($username)->user_id; // error is right here when first in the list is a username
            if (!$user_id){
                array_push($invalid_users["invalid_username"], $username);
            }
            self::delete_student($user_id);
        }
    }
    return $invalid_users;
}
```

This is the get_by_username() for reference:

```
public static function get_by_username($username){
    global $database;
    $statement = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $statement->execute(array($username));
    $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $statement->closeCursor();
    if($row){
        $user = new User($row);
        return $user;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: which line does the error relate to?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the whole raw error message please

Comment: @nogad I commented which lines the error relates to

Comment: @eeetee just done

Comment: `$user_id = self::get_by_username($name);` remove `->user_id`

Comment: I still receive the same error when trying to retrieve the property later

Answer (score 0):

After further extensive testing, it turns out that despite the error appearing in the backend php code, the real issue was that AngularJS wasn't sending the delete request body via the shortcut method. 
Apologies to anyone who has spent as much time as me researching php to find the error in this code.